# Accessing Views from bin folder where request validation is disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a scenario where we are accessing views from bin folder of a project so that we can use it commonly across other project e.g. Say a common gui project which has common views in the bin folder and then other GUI projects which use these.
Everything works fine but the issue is we have request validation disabled across all projects but when we access views from bin folder somehow request validation takes places and we get familiar error "potentially dangerous request.form value has been detected...".If we move views to normal view location it works fine

Any idea why.

EDIT :

Just to be clear what I am asking is that in current scenario we have our views inside the bin folder that is views location is something like "~/bin/debug/Views/Employee/Create.aspx" instead of "~/Views/Employee/Create.aspx".Also we have request validation disabled i.e. validaterequest = false.But still in this case when I access views from bin folder request validation is triggered and when I move back my views to  "~/Views/Employee/Create.aspx" it does not trigger request validation (as expected).Question why validation is being triggered in case of views accessed from bin folder.

Why we are using views from bin is so that these views can be shared across other GUI projects.

Comment: I think you just need a web.config in that directory that disables request validation, like you have in your `~\Views`.  Also, doing what you are doing is a really bad idea, but it's your site...

Comment: Ok let me try that... since you mentioned it's bad idea... what would be the best way

Comment: Many ways, depends on what you want.  Make a dll with embedded resources and share that, then load them as resource streams.  Make a base directory or a directory in `~/Views/` and stuff them in there, and add a check for them when the app starts up.  Add a `shared views` area, put them in there, and then render them that way... But `bin\debug` is not good.  I can't image that is part of a stable build process, what happens when you do a clean...

Comment: Awesome...that resolved it.After reading your comment and doing some google searching that make sense that this may not be good way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked... and google is our friend... I just know it's possible, I've not had to do it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is adding a `web.config` in that directory.  The web.config should disable request validation, like your standard one does.

The easiest way is probably to copy the one from your normal `~/Views` directory, and then remove anything you don't need.